# Error Returning Value From Switch Case?

Tags: actionscript-3, return, switch-statement

after coding a custom event in AS3, i've come across a curious problem:

```
override public function toString():String
    {
    switch  (type)
            {
            case CHANGE:    return formatToString("HistoryEvent", "type", "action", "name", "data");
            case ABILITY:   return formatToString("HistoryEvent", "type", "undoable", "redoable");
            }
    }
```

the above code returns the following compile-time error:

> 1170: Function does not return a
>   value.

i can remedy the problem easily by adding `return null;` at the end of the function, but that's redundant and it annoys me that it seems to be the only solution.

why is returning a value from a switch case not seen by the compiler?  is this an issue specific to the AS3 compiler or am i actually attempting something here that is *so* completely dangerous and adverse that it shadows counterculturists the world over.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible that your switch doesn't match, and in that case the function can't return anything. That's why the compiler complains. Adding `default: return null;` to your switch statement solves the problem as well as adding `return null` at the end of your function.

Comment: I was having this same issue. This is a nice solution and your explanation helped me understand why this happens, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to add default block to your switch statement.Then the compiler won't complain to return value